Error when using Python to connect to Oracle Server
Python 3.12.6
Oracle SQL Developer  Version 23.1.1.345
I wish to test whether my Python script can communicate with the server. This is only the first step in developing a program. The script should get password to the server, then output "Successfully connected to Oracle Database".
Instead, I get an error that the database is actively refusing connections even though I can log into the database via SQL Developer.
Below is the Python script
import getpass
import oracledb

pw = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")

connection = oracledb.connect(
    user="rep_dlp",
    password=pw,
    dsn="localhost/DEV_PROTECT")

print("Successfully connected to Oracle Database")

cursor = connection.cursor()

Here is the error output
D:\Reporting>python connect.py
Enter password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 322, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 225, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_phase_one
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 362, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_tcp
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 865, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 850, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Reporting\connect.py", line 6, in <module>
    connection = oracledb.connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 1169, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 551, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 424, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 420, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 380, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 361, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 327, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\errors.py", line 195, in _raise_err
    raise error.exc_type(error) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=ii7F2d6/yPjm22VqmzWk9g==).
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it


Try localhost:1521/DEV_PROTECT

@p3consulting I tried and same error persists

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" This could be for many reasons including blocked by the firewall, the database isn't running, connecting to the wrong server, etc.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

I updated question, please re-open.

Show what connection string you are using in SQL Developer.  Are you running SQL Dev on the same machine you are running Python?

@ChristopherJones correct, i am running Python script and SQL Dev both on same machine. And my connection string is oracledb.connect(     user="rep_dlp",     password=pw,     dsn="localhost/DEV_PROTECT")

You still haven't shown the SQL Developer connection string - is that a basic connection, also to localhost and port 1521? Or a TNS connection - in which case how is the TNS entry defined? You said "communicate with the server" which suggests the database is somewhere else, not on your PC, but it's unclear...

Ok @AlexPoole that may be the problem, ie connection string. I will revisit this
